# How can i solve blank page? ( React beginner )

Tags: reactjs

After i changed App.js code.. The page show blank page with 3 error code continusly

[image]

I tried to fix it for 4 hours..

Now I can't hold on anymore..

Can you help me..?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        Hello, React!!
      </div>
    );
  }
} 
export default App;
```

Comment: The error is not related to your component code. As the error message says, you have syntax error in your `manifest.json` file. Can you please post that file as well? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
I tryed live server every i tried to compile.. not npm start..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are running the app with live server of visual studio code. To run react app you need to run following command in the root of react app.

If you are using npm then run this command :-

```
npm start
```

If you are using yarn then run this command :-

```
yarn start
```

Comment: ...  I was fool :( 
You find out  exactily what i did..
Thank you very much :)